# Close custom dialog when Enter is pressed in input field

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, input, dialog

I've designed (using the GUI designer within Netbeans) a small dialog with two radio buttons and a number spinner.

1. If I press Enter while the focus is on one of the radio buttons, the dialog correctly closes, but if the focus is on the spinner, I have to Tab away from it in order to use the Enter key.

   2. How do I instruct the dialog that Enter really means "accept and close"?
   3. Alternatively, how do I instruct (each) input field to relay an Enter to the "accept and close" handler?
   4. Similarly, how do I instruct the dialog that Esc really means "cancel and close" even when the focus is on the spinner (or other field)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I pressed enter when entering keywords and accidentally published the question with out a, well, question. Sorry!

Comment: @KlaymenDK search here for question tagged by key-bindings

Comment: `If I press Enter while the focus is on one of the radio buttons, the dialog correctly closes`  - So how do you do this? Do you use a KeyListener, Key Bindings or some other approach. We can't guess what your code is currently doing, so we can't suggest what you might be doing wrong. When you ask a question post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem so we don't have to guess what you may or may not be doing.

Comment: So how did I do that? I'm sorry to say, I've no idea, except that I used the Netbeans GUI editor. I'm rather new to swing, and brand new to Netbeans, so "who knows" (not me) how it wires things up. I'm learning though!

Answer (score 1):

> how do I instruct (each) input field to relay an Enter to the "accept and close" handler?

The easiest approach is to define a "default button" on the dialog. Then when Enter is pressed the default button will be activated. Check out Enter Key and Button for different ways to do this.

> how do I instruct the dialog that Esc really means "cancel and close"

Use `Key Bindings` to invoke the Action of your Cancel button.

First you define an `Action` to be used by the button:

```
public class CancelAction extends AbstractAction
{
    public CancelAction()
    {
        super("Cancel");
        putValue( Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_C) );
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Window window = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getActiveWindow();

        if (window != null)
        {
            WindowEvent windowClosing = new WindowEvent(window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
            window.dispatchEvent(windowClosing);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you add the `Action` to the button so the user can use the mouse:

```
CancelAction cancelAction = new CancelAction();
cancelButton.setAction( cancelAction );
dialog.add(cancelButton);
```

Now you can use Key Bindings to bind the Escape key to the CancelAction so the user can use the keyboard:

```
KeyStroke escapeKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false);
getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(escapeKeyStroke, "ESCAPE");
getRootPane().getActionMap().put("ESCAPE", cancelAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason I had problems is that *a spinner is really a compound control*, and the text (well, number) field is an component of that. So *I needed to hook up the events to that subcomponent*, rather than to the spinner itself:

```
// Make Ok/Cancel work when JSpinner has focus
    getSpinnerField(jSpinnerOffset).addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            doOk();
        }
    });
```

where "getSpinnerField()" is just a shorthand in a private method:

```
private JFormattedTextField getSpinnerField(JSpinner spinner) {
    return ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
}
```

Doing this, the Esc key automagically becomes able to dismiss the dialog.